# Linux в целом и kali

Tags: linux

Вопрос будет кратким, но, скорее всего, непонятным.Но я попытаюсь донести. 
Итак, если я хочу начать изучать linux после долгого использования винды(что-то вроде перехода с красоты на функционал), а потом kali linux, то насколько сложно будет к нему адаптироваться(я это про kali)? Точнее, будет ли отличаться в каком-то смысле их поведение? Например, в где-то в linux будет терминал, a в kali это будет ланимрет, чтобы вызвать его в linux нужна будет одна команда, а в kali десять. я это имею ввиду

Comment: Kali — это не аналог Linux, а его сборка. Иными словами, набор из предустановленных программ и графической оболочки, развёрнутых *поверх* Linux; родные линуксовые утилиты и средства никуда при этом не деваются. Соответственно, и сравнивать его надо с другими сборками. Эдак, «Ubuntu/Debian/Gentoo/PuppyLinux/etc и Kali».

Comment: В kali нет вкусностей, вы не привыкните, в основном любят сетевые администраторы ковырятся в сетях и серверах.

Comment: Присоединюсь к ребятам выше,тем более kali сделана на основе то-ли ubuntu то ли debian. кароче принципиальной разницы не будет.. и там и там много-чего через терминал делать надо. но на кали  стоит тот же gnome  как графическая оболочка.. после Винды немного непривычно. в общем в кали затолкали много прилаг для тестирования безопасности разом..  а в остальном тот же обыкновенный дебианподобный linux

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас конечно закидают томатами, что я даю ответ а не пишу в комментарий...

> Для общего понимания: Я пользовался обеими системами, на достаточно
>   хорошем уровне. Так что, я понимаю о чём пишу. К тому же я сам однажды
>   пересел из под окон под пингвина.

В первую очередь, зачем вам именно kali? Если вы посмотрели фильм про грозных хакеров и решили, что настало время великих свершений. То смею вас огорчить, знание одного linux-а да и самой kali, не сделает из вас хакера.

По поводу отличий kali от других дистрибутивов. Это чисто формальность. Вы спокойно можете накатить любой терминал или ПО, с которым вам комфортно работать. Насколько я помню kali поставляется с оболочкой ghome, так что особых отличий быть не должно.

Поймите одну суть, Linux - это ядро. А все команды и прочее. Это оболочка (Кстати команды практически всегда одни и те же самые).
Полезные ссылки:

[Очень рекомендую более подробно все перечитать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux)

[Неплохая статья по теме](https://techrocks.ru/2017/10/25/switching-from-windows-to-linux/)

Comment: `В первую очередь, зачем вам именно kali? Если вы посмотрели фильм про грозных хакеров и решили, что настало время великих свершений. То смею вас огорчить, знание одного linux-а да и самой kali, не сделает из вас хакера.` - Лишнее.